# how can I make my menu responsive correctly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

how can I make my menu responsive correctly, on the cell phone it looks like this

on the computer it looks like this:
[enter image description here][2]

When I select an option from the menu the menu does not disappear, but if it goes to the selected section

There is someone who can guide me, so that my menu is responsive, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write your css for mobile devices by implementing these lines of code:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
    css goes here
}
```

Comment: If it works, but the computer menu appears as the image of the menu on the cell phone, that is, the words do not come out

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `display: flex` instead of floating. As it has been said, you can use media queries to write device specific css rules.

Another option to easily create responsive layouts is to use grid-libraries as [Flexboxgrid](http://flexboxgrid.com/).